# Node.Js mongoose find not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get the documents from my MongoDB by using mongoose "find" method. But I'm not able to get records. It did not returns any error. Here is my code

Server.js

```
var express     =   require('express');
var bodyparser  =   require('body-parser');
var mongoose    =   require('mongoose');
var cors        =   require('cors');

var app         =   express();

var http        =   require('http').Server(app);
var io          =   require('socket.io')(http);

mongoose.promise    =   global.promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb");
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'server'));

var api     =   require('./routes/apihandler')(app, express, io);

app.use('/alerts', api);

http.listen(3000, function(err){
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Listening PORT' + config.port);
  }
});
```

apihandler.js

```
var request     =   require('request');
var express     =   require('express');
var alertRoutes =   require('../../services/routes/alertRoutes');
var api         =   express.Router();

module.exports  =   function(app, express, io){
    api.get('/getAllAlerts/:retailerId/:loyaltyId', getAllAlerts);
    return api;
}

function getAllAlerts(req, res, callback) {
    console.log('apihandler');

    try {

        alertRoutes.getAllAlerts(req,res,callback);



    }
    catch(err) {
        res.send({"status" : "error",  message: err.mes});
    }

}
```

Manager.js

```
var alertModel          =   require('./../models/alertModel');
alertModel.find({}, function (err, docs) {
   console.log(err);
   console.log(docs);
});
```

Model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var alertSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id:{ type: String },
    alertType:{ type: Number},
    retailerId: { type: String },
    loyaltyId: { type: String }, 
    email: { type: String }, 
    description: { type: String},     
    locationId:{type: String }, 
    reason:{type: String},
    reasonDescription:{type: String},
    capturedReasonsList:mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
},{ collection: 'alerts' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('alerts', alertSchema);
```

alertRoutes.js

```
//Get all Alerts
function getAllAlerts(req, res, callback){
  console.log('getAllAlerts');
=
  var srchData  = {
      retailerId:req.params.retailerId,
      loyaltyId:req.params.loyaltyId
  };
 retailerId='+req.params.retailerId+'&loyaltyId='+req.params.loyaltyId;
  alertManager.getAlert(srchData,function(err,alertDetails){
    console.log('alertDetails',alertDetails);
      if (err) throw err;
      if(alertDetails && alertDetails.length > 0){
          res.status(200).send(alertDetails);
      }else{
          res.status(200).send({success: false,message: 'Alert Details not Found'});
      }
  });
// });
}
```

I can able to get into Manager js. But the find query is not working

Please Help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Try this : 
var alertModel          =   mongoose.model('alerts');
alertModel.find({}, function (err, docs) {
   if(!err)
   console.log(docs);
});

Comment: @Md.NazmulHossainBilash - Tried this. no luck

Comment: is your require path valid?

Comment: @shaishabroy - Yes. Valid

Comment: Does your callback get actually called, i.e. do you see "test" in the console if you would place `console.log('test')` in your callback?

Comment: @DAXaholic - No. I could not get anything in the callback.

Comment: @DAXaholic - I checked the connection. connection is fine. mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb");

Comment: @DAXaholic - I added more code

Comment: save also not working. am i missed anything

Comment: @DAXaholic - It's fired

Comment: Your model file is named `Model.js`, your module export is `alerts` and your required is `alertModel`. This is really ambiguous. Rename them with the same name

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes. I am working with these codes & it works for me.

Model :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

  var alertSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    id:{ type: String },
    alertType:{ type: Number},
    retailerId: { type: String },
    loyaltyId: { type: String }, 
    email: { type: String }, 
    description: { type: String},     
    locationId:{type: String }, 
    reason:{type: String},
    reasonDescription:{type: String},
    capturedReasonsList:mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed

  });
  mongoose.model('Alert',alertSchema);
```

Server Code :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var alertModel = mongoose.model('Alert');
alertModel.find().exec(function (err, docs) {
   if(!err)
   console.log(docs);
});
```

Comment: Whats the output ?

Comment: it didn't returns anything.

Comment: R you sure in your database, have values ? check the database & please inform me. You can use robomongo

Comment: checked records in db with any DB visualizer ?

Comment: actually my callback function is not fired.

Comment: You can use promise for solving async problems or callback. I think it will be best to use bluebird promise

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the find is just never called... Do some console.log before the find to make sure.

Provide the code of "getAlert", we cannot see where and how Manager.js is used.